# Occlusion culles too early

Tags: unity-game-engine, occlusion, occlusion-culling

My occlusion setup is wrong somehow because it ocludes too early sometimes

Here it looks good the red arrow marks the problem tunnel
[image]

If i move the camera just a decimeter or two back the tunnel section is culled too early, you can see that the green visibly lines are wrong, look in the preview and you see the result outlined in red
[image]

Here's my area setup
[image]

Any ideas why it does this?

Comment: Make a area for each of the two tunnels, does it make a difference?

Comment: Thanks for reply, no difference. :/ Btw, this is not the only place it occludes viisble stuff

Comment: What if you increase the far plane distance on the camera?

Comment: This has nothing todo with that, its the oclussion that causes this, look on the picture second picture.

Comment: This scene is bassed on a asset which is very modular, the tunnel for instance is built with tunnel segments that are only 2 meters long. I have tried playing with the smallest ocludeer setting, does not help. Maybe I should try mesh baker and devide the scene into bigger segments?